# J-Invariant of elliptic curve (Frey-Hellegouarch), discriminant and positive definite kernels, similarities?

Tags: number-theory, hilbert-spaces, elliptic-curves, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I asked this question at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361894/discriminant-of-elliptic-curve-frey-hellegouarch-j-invariant-and-positive-def) but did not receive an answer:

Consider the Frey-Hellegouarch curve given $a,b$ natural numbers:

$$y^3= x(x-\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)})(x+\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)})$$

Then the discriminant is given by $\Delta = \Delta(a,b) = 16 \left(\frac{ab(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)^3}\right)^2$.

A similarity $s:X\times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined in [Encyclopedia of Distances](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-30958-8) (p. 3) as:

1. $s(x,y) \ge 0 \forall x,y \in X$
2. $s(x,y) = s(y,x) \forall x,y \in X$
3. $s(x,y) \le s(x,x) \forall x,y \in X$
4. $s(x,y) = s(x,x) \iff x=y$

A positive definite kernel $k$ is a positive definite function on some set $X$.
A "kernel-similarity" is a function $f$ which is a kernel and a similiarity.
One can prove that $\frac{1}{16 \left ( \frac{ab(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)^3}\right )^2}$ is a kernel-similarity.

If $f$ is a "kernel-similarity" such that $f(a,a) = f(b,b) \forall a,b \in X$ then:
$$d(a,b) = \sqrt{f(a,a) + f(b,b) - 2f(a,b)}$$
defines a metric and the corresponding metric space can be embedded into a Hilbert space (or for finite $X$ can be embedded to an Euclidean space).

It is conjectured that $\frac{1}{\operatorname{rad}(\frac{ab(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)^3})}$ is a positive definite kernel over the natural numbers. (One can prove that it is a similarity over the natural numbers.). This similarity has to do with the "conductor" of the elliptic curve above. (Although I am not familiar with elliptic curves, but trying to read about them).

My 1). question is if there are other families of elliptic curves indexed by $a,b$ such that the reciprocal of the determinant over all the family of considered elliptic curves:

$$\frac{1}{\Delta(a,b)}=k(a,b)=s(a,b)$$

is a "kernel-similarity" over the natural numbers.

This would allow to apply the theory of Hilbert spaces over the family of elliptic curves.

The j-invariant is given by:

$$j(a,b) = \frac{16^2(a^2+ab+b^2)^3}{a^2b^2(a+b)^2}$$

It seems that:

$$\frac{1}{j(a,b)}$$

is positive definite.

**Question: Is $$\frac{1}{j(a,b)}$$ a positive definite function over the natural numbers?**

Comment: @ViktorStein: I had written this question and deleted the user account for some reason. In Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel#Kernels_and_distances) it is mentioned that the function is a pseudometric, if $k$ is a kernel. Since I require $k=s$ to be also a similarity function, then $x=y \iff d(x,y)=0$ and thus $d$ is a metric.

Comment: This question has an answer at the corresponding MathOverflow question.